# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure when trying to grab a random line from Project Gutenberg

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to grab a random line from The Adventures of Tom Sawyer. Here's my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/74/74-h/74-h.htm").timeout(10*1000).get();
            String body = doc.select("p").text();
            String[] bodytext = body.split("\\.");
            int randomLine = rand.nextInt(bodytext.length);
            if (bodytext[randomLine].startsWith(" \"")) {
                System.out.println("Random line from " + bodytext[randomLine] + ".\"");
            }
            else {
            System.out.println("Random line from " + bodytext[randomLine] + ".");
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication8.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}
```

Here's the error message I'm receiving:

```
SEVERE: null
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2011)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1113)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1363)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1391)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:563)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
    at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.main(JavaApplication8.java:27)
```

Line 27 is `Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/74/74-h/74-h.htm").timeout(10*1000).get();`

What's going wrong? I did this a few months ago and I had no trouble, but when I came back to it this week I'm getting this handshake failure error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, if you can, updating java. I don't know why but jdk1.8.0_25 worked for me while jdk1.7.0_51 and jdk1.7.0_79 didn't (those versions gave the same error you mention)

I'll try to investigate further to improve the answer but I hope this helps you.

Hint: you can use vm argument `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to get more information about the error.

UPDATE:

As @dave_thompson_085 pointed, in jdk1.7 tls1.2 is disabled by default. You can enable it but gutenberg.org  is requiring `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` or `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` that are not supported by java 1.7.

I tried to add them using other provider with no luck, so... it seems that using jdk1.8 is the best option. If someone achieves to use `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`in jdk1.7 it would be nice to know.

Comment: According to ssllabs, [www.]gutenborg.org is 152.19.134.47 and accepts **TLS1.2 only**, and their cert is dated Sep 22 which suggest they might have made changes then. Java 7 SSL client by default does not offer TLS 1.2 (or 1.1) although a program can change this, at least assuming Jsoup uses the default SSLSocketFactory and it appears to. Java 8 client by default does offer them. Troubingly however my DNS resolves differently and so do the rather suspicious-looking (klczy.com?) ones I get from afilias.

Comment: thanks @dave_thompson_085, you're right, I'm updating the answer